# Embedding OpenEJB in a TestCase using javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer

Tags: jakarta-ee, openejb

**Embedding OpenEJB in a TestCase using javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.**

EJBContainer container = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();

always returns "null".

How to instantiate the EJBContainer and get the context for looking up EJB 3.0 local stateless session Bean for unit testing?

I would like to get the context from the created container rather than from initial context, how it can be done?

Comment: can you show us the testcase code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenEJB, the OpenEJB 4.0.0 -beta is found to be supporting java ee embeddable API and with this we can embed the container in our testcase like,

```
    EJBContainer ejbContainer = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
```

In previous versions of OpenEJB we can't do like this and hence we use "LocalInitialContextFactory" to create the context.

Answer (score 2):

> How to instantiate the EJBContainer and get the context for looking up EJB 3.0 local stateless session Bean for unit testing?

(I think you intended to ask about EJB 3.1. The `javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer` was added in EJB 3.1) You could do that like this:

```
 EJBContainer ejbContainer = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
Object object = ejbContainer.getContext().lookup("java:global/simple-stateless/CalculatorBean");
```

Have a look at the [Simple Stateless](http://openejb.apache.org/examples-trunk/simple-stateless/README.html) example.

Comment: I have tried this before, but i'm getting "null" when instantiating like this                                                           

EJBContainer ejbContainer = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();

Any configurations needed?